# Make a attendace student report using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some `csv` table from google form for attendance report. The data looks like this

```
df1= pd.read_csv("12-9-2020.csv")
df1

Name            StudentID
Robert C        102
Jessica Myla    103
Nana D          105

df2= pd.read_csv("12-10-2020.csv")
df2

Name            StudentID
J Myla          103
Harris Kurt     104
Nana Duncan     105
```

I have many tables that I want to make a compilation attendance report. The basic compilation attendance report looks like this:

```
df_Basic
Name             StudentID  12/9/2020   12/10/2020
Robert Case      102        0           0
Jessica Myla     103        0           0
Harris Kurt      104        0           0
Nana Duncan      105        0           0
```

I want to input the data form `df1, df2` to the compilation attendance report.  If the student attend the class, it must be as 1 and the spell of the student name will match with the compilation attendance report format.

The desired result looks like this:

```
df_Result
Name          StudentID 12/9/2020   12/10/2020
Robert Case   102       1           0
Jessica Myla  103       1           1
Harris Kurt   104       0           1
Nana Duncan   105       1           1
```

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full solution:

1. `df` - dynamically read in all files into one dataframe from a specific folder on your desktop (and create `Date` column with `assign` and derive date from the filename). YOU must specify this in the `files` variable
2. `df_attendance` - with `.groupby`, return `1` or `0` by `StudentID` and put `Date` on columns
3. `df_names` - Normalize `Name` data by choosing the longest name per `ID` as the `Name`
4. `df_attendance` - `join` the two dataframes `df_attendance` and `df_names`

---

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(r'Desktop\Students\*.csv')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(os.path.basename(f)[:-4]))
                for f in files])
df_attendance = (df.groupby(['StudentID', df['Date'].dt.date]).size()
                   .unstack(1).fillna(0).astype(int))
df_names = (df.groupby(['StudentID'])['Name'].apply(list)
              .apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(y) == 
                                max([len(z) for z in x])][0])).to_frame() # this reads.. per student choose the name that is the longest name
df_Result = df_names.join(df_attendance).reset_index()
df_Result
Out[1]: 
   StudentID          Name  2020-12-09  2020-12-10
0        102      Robert C           1           0
1        103  Jessica Myla           1           1
2        104   Harris Kurt           0           1
3        105   Nana Duncan           1           1
```

---

---

If you want to change the formats of the dates in the date column, then you can run the below code, which is very similar:

```
files = glob.glob(r'Desktop\Students\*.csv')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(os.path.basename(f)[:-4]))
                for f in files]).sort_values(['StudentID', 'Date'])
df_attendance = (df.groupby(['StudentID', df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')], sort=False).size()
                   .unstack(1).fillna(0).astype(int))
df_names = (df.groupby(['StudentID'])['Name'].apply(list)
              .apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(y) == 
                                max([len(z) for z in x])][0])).to_frame()
df_Result = df_names.join(df_attendance).reset_index()
df_Result

Out[2]: 
   StudentID          Name  12/09/20  12/10/20
0        102      Robert C         1         0
1        103  Jessica Myla         1         1
2        104   Harris Kurt         0         1
3        105   Nana Duncan         1         1
```

Per your comment, you can do something like this. *Please note it is BETTER to use StudentID instead of Name for a direct match, so just replace "StudentID" with "Name" if you use that*:

```
df_list = pd.read_csv(file) # pass the filepath of you file and must have column "Name:
df_list = df_list[~(df_list['Name'].isin(df_Result['Name']))] #find students not in the file
df_Result = pd.concat([df_Result, df_list[['Name']]]).fillna(0)
df_Result
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @david How about if there is a student who never filled google form, however, his or her name exists in the basic compilation attendance report. His or her name will not exist in the end of the compilation attendance report.

Comment: Hi @Arief that is an additional problem, but see the bottom of my answer. If you need any more details kindly create a new stackoverflow question and reference that question back to this one and I or someone else can answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for two dataframes:

```
df1.set_index('StudentID', inplace=True)
df1.loc[:, '12-9-2020.csv'] = 1

df2.set_index('StudentID', inplace=True)
df2.loc[:, '12-10-2020.csv'] = 1
df1 = df1.join(df2, how='outer', rsuffix='_')
df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].combine_first(df1['Name_'])
df1.drop('Name_', axis=1, inplace=True)

df1.fillna(0).reset_index()
```

For more dataframes, repeat the lines 3-7, as needed.

Comment: Thank you, I got an error - name 'joint' is not defined -

Comment: A typo. It was supposed to be `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Probably do it with

```py
df1= pd.read_csv("12-9-2020.csv")
df1

Name            StudentID
Robert C        102
Jessica Myla    103
Nana D          105

df2= pd.read_csv("12-10-2020.csv")
# get ids from second table
ids_of_presenties = df2['StudentID'].values.tolist()

# in first dataframe create a date column
current_date = '12/9/2020'
df1[current_date] = 0
df1[df1['StudentID'].isin(ids_of_presenties)][current_date] = 1 # mark the attendance of the only student present.
```

Don't have your dataframe. hope it's good